# View shifts up by 20px after closing the modal view

Tags: iphone, frame, statusbar, navigationbar

I am working on storyboard based application (iPhone). Application has a Navigation Controller to start with. We are integrating an existing application with it. Thus we need to load the NIB file on click of a button.

```
 NSBundle *someBundle = [NSBundle category_bundle ];    
 MainWindow *aViewController = [[MainWindow alloc] 
                          initWithNibName:nibName 
                          bundle:someBundle];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:aViewController animated:YES];
```

The existing application then loads another VC.

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:mySecondView animated:YES];
```

This view again comes from NIB.

This view then uses a singelton to get the instance of MainWindow (loaded in first step) and request it to show a modal view. "Bad Design" but I can not change it as this is an existing application and I need to deliver the integration tomorrow.

Modal is shown as -

```
[self presentModalViewController:aModal animated:YES];
```

We are opening the modal in landscape and for that in its viewWillAppear we are using this code-

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = self.interfaceOrientation;
```

and in `viewDidDisappear`

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"5.0")) {
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = self.parentViewController.interfaceOrientation;
        } else {
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = self.presentingViewController.interfaceOrientation;
        }
```

**Question**:

The problem is that UIView of MainWindow moves up by 20px after the modal pop up has been closed. I have tried to reset the frame. Also tried to hide the status bar but then status bar partially hides the navigation bar, to resolve this we tried to hide the navigation bar after the status bar has been made visible and then showing it again, but with no success.

Please let me know how can I resolve this issue.